# When I write the command (ip addr show) in master node don't show me the address. How to solve this?

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

I install a multi-node cluster of Hadoop on Ubuntu using VirtualBox when I write the command `noor@hadoopmaster$ IP address show` that don't show the right IP address for the master and the slaves. What is the problem?

Comment: Your post is not a bad question, but at the same time, it is a question where you spend little-to-no time to write. If you spent around 30 seconds writing it, then why would you expect that someone will spend time to answer it? Please read Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), in order to improve your question quality and get good solutions by other community members.

Answer (score 0):

`ip addr show` will only show you one machine's network interfaces, ever. This isn't a problem with Hadoop.

There's no specific way to know what the "right" address should be, but Hadoop manages a `slaves` file that should be populated with the externally resolvable addresses of the other machines.

If you're having issues managing this file, Apache Ambari can automate that process for you (and install a full Hadoop cluster itself)

Comment: In my case, i have only one live node on hadoopmaster:50070 (i have recheck all configuration many time)
There are my JPS:
on master
3458 ResourceManager
3155 DataNode
3559 NodeManager
3032 NameNode
5406 Jps
3311 SecondaryNameNode
on slave1
4666 Jps
on slave2                                                                  4677 Jps
Please help me. Thank

Comment: I have not manually installed Hadoop ever without using Ambari. Not sure if I can help you. You will have to manually start datanodes on the other machines, then look at logs to find any errors, then check JPS... You will not see other processes on other servers from only one machine's JPS output